# Indexing type with generic keyof to type infer within an if-condition

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have a function which receives a key of a type to index an object or undefined to use for a class constructor.

```js
class Instance {
  type: keyof OptionsMap
  constructor(type: keyof OptionsMap) {
    this.type = type
  }
}
class ClassA extends Instance {
  constructor(type: 'nothing') {
    super(type)
  }
}
class ClassB extends Instance {
  opts: Record<string, any>
  constructor(type: 'something', opts: Record<string, any>){
    super(type)
    this.opts = opts
  }
}
class ClassC extends Instance {
  opts: { name: string }
  constructor(type: 'thing', opts: { name: string }){
    super(type)
    this.opts = opts
  }
}
interface OptionsMap {
  nothing: undefined
  something: Record<string, any>
  thing: { name: string }
}

function foo<T extends keyof OptionsMap>(type: T, options: OptionsMap[T]): Instance {
  if (type === 'nothing') {
    return new ClassA(type)
  } else if (type === 'something') {
    return new ClassB(type, options)
  } else if (type === 'thing') {
    return new ClassC(type, options)
  } else {
    throw Error('Invalid type: ' + type)
  }
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECSB2EAuZ7AKbQN4ChrSQE8AHdALmgGt1CB7AM2gHlikBLWxAWTGL2mCdkAJwCuwJLWEAKIqQrU6jFuyE9iASmz98SABZsIAOjmYAvARLp%20AXxx3QkGAGFwUAILR0ADyTp4ACYwCMioGNr4gohIYhJSslYUAOTwtPps8ADmSVq4%20PgQoqQyphq29jiOUNCuTgBCXr7%20QXDRYZh50LSsEBQASuiCwgEAPCIZmQA00KiEAHz8USLikiWJ0EkQtAC26OlZSdPdSL3QA0Oj41nTs3ManQVF6GukZfkEBsbHMBbf5XYZPzCehgcIqDjcXgRaCpfaZCiiQLoegZdABfhbXZw-qDKSXGITG7weYVHD0RESCHQei0WgjAAqjT8gRgigYzFYEIg6jmCXk0HpR05Qgo4LUvAA2vSALoaCghFBoDr8NiMPnmMwWFJpAwHXI6aDCPaiYTwGHoADuNTcEHc6re0BsXhAEEwqug6ugmq1mL2uuy%20veRqQJrN8Et1vq6qFqkQDqd6Bdyve%20mEtCtAFFhGmZEkEAA3MAgNgBSz8pLQADUZfQ8fsQA)

However, this throws:

```
Argument of type 'Record<string, any> | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Record<string, any>'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'Record<string, any>'
```

How can I make the options type-safe? I am using TypeScript `5.3.3`

Comment: Control flow and generics don't play nicely together today. If you want `if` blocks then you want to avoid generics. Luckily your example doesn't need generics; you can use a destructured discriminated union as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/N5ak9N). Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Oh that's how. I looked up one of your previous answers but didn't quite get it to work. Thanks a ton, makes sense. I actually did manage to somehow hack a working solution which works for my particular case of instantiating classes although it's a bit ugly (as my actual code also omits the second parameter) [playground](https://tsplay.dev/m0evPW)

Comment: Actually switching in your version to **...args: FooArgs** I am pretty much able to get identical result with less crazy type object compared to my constructor version. Only difference is that the undefined value is now required in the function signature but that's fine for me. But please, if you can write up the answer i'll gladly accept it

Comment: Actually **...[type, options]: FooArgs** works as well

Comment: Yeah, `...[type, options]` is what I meant to put in there, sorry. I'll write it up when I get a chance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript currently (as of 5.3) can't really handle [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) and [control flow analysis](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#control-flow-analysis) at the same time.  TypeScript can use control flow analysis to conclude that `type === 'nothing'` narrows the type of `type`, but it has no effect whatsoever on the type parameter `T`.  So `OptionsMap[T]` is also unaffected, and you get errors.

There is a longstanding open feature request at [microsoft/TypeScript#33014](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33014) to allow control flow to affect generic types themselves. It even looks like this might become part of the language soon-ish, since it's mentioned in the TS5.5 roadmap ([microsoft/TypeScript#57475](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/57475)). So maybe your code will just start working someday without change.

Until and unless that happens, though, you'll need to work around it.

---

So you will want to either refactor to use generics without control flow analysis, or control flow analysis without generics.  Generic functions are mostly useful where the output type depends on the input type. But you've just got `Instance` as the return type. So let's try giving up on generics.

If `type` and `options` were properties of a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions) type, then control flow analysis would kick in, so that checking the [literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) of `type` would narrow the type of `options`.

Now, as function parameters, they don't seem to be properties of a discriminated union type.  But you could make your function take a [rest parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) of a discriminated union [tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types), where the `0` index corresponds to `type` and the `1` index corresponds to `options`:

```
type FooArgs = 
  [type: "nothing", options: undefined] | 
  [type: "something", options: Record<string, any>] | 
  [type: "thing", options: { name: string; }]

function foo(...args: FooArgs): Instance {
    if (args[0] === 'nothing') {
        return new ClassA(args[0])
    } else if (args[0] === 'something') {
        return new ClassB(args[0], args[1])
    } else if (args[0] === 'thing') {
        return new ClassC(args[0], args[1])
    } else {
        throw Error('Invalid type: ' + args[0])
    }
}
```

(I used [labeled tuple elements](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#labeled-tuple-elements), but those are just for documentation; you still have to use `0` and `1` to index them, not `type` and `options`.) That code works, but it's a little annoying.

The first annoyance is that we had to write out `FooArgs` manually, which is redundant. But we can make the compiler *compute* `FooArgs` from `OptionsMap`:

```
type FooArgs = { [K in keyof OptionsMap]: 
  [type: K, options: OptionsMap[K]] 
}[keyof OptionsMap]
```

That's a *discriminated object type* as coined in [microsoft/TypeScript#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109). It basically walks through each member of `keyof OptionsMap` and produces a two element tuple for each member, and then produces the union of those tuples.

The second annoyance is all that `args[0]` and `args[1]` inside the function.
Luckily, there is support for [*destructured* discriminated unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-6.html#control-flow-analysis-for-destructured-discriminated-unions), so you can copy the members of the rest parameter into `type` and `options` variables:

```
function foo(...[type, options]: FooArgs): Instance {
    if (type === 'nothing') {
        return new ClassA(type)
    } else if (type === 'something') {
        return new ClassB(type, options)
    } else if (type === 'thing') {
        return new ClassC(type, options)
    } else {
        throw Error('Invalid type: ' + type)
    }
}
```

That's pretty close to being optional. It would be nice if you could just write `type, options` instead of `...[type, options]`, but you can't [annotate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#parameter-type-annotations) *pairs* of parameters.  If you're willing to refactor a `function` declaration to a `const`, though, then you can get there, by having the compiler infer the type of `type` and `options` [contextually](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html#contextual-typing):

```
const foo: (...args: FooArgs) => Instance = (type, options) => {
    if (type === 'nothing') {
        return new ClassA(type)
    } else if (type === 'something') {
        return new ClassB(type, options)
    } else if (type === 'thing') {
        return new ClassC(type, options)
    } else {
        throw Error('Invalid type: ' + type)
    }
}
```

Which looks good.

---

So there you go. If you don't want to wait to see if generics and control flow analysis start working together, you can refactor away from generics to destructured discriminated unions and get the behavior you're looking for.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&removeComments=true&target=99&jsx=4&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&inlineSourceMap=true&inlineSources=true&isolatedModules=true&noImplicitOverride=true&noErrorTruncation=true#code/MYGwhgzhAECSB2EAuZ7AKbQN4CgCQSAngA7oBc0A1uoQPYBm0A8sUgJa2ICyYx+wnZACcArsCS0hACiKkK1OoxbtBPYgEps+AgAs2EAHSzMAXmjH8AXxzXQkGAGFwUAILR0ADyTp4AExgIyKgYWngCiEii4pIyJOTQAOTwtEh68ADmCZq4eHgQIqTSxupWNjh2UNBO9gBC7l4+-nARwZg5tKwQFABK6AJCvgA8wmwZADTQqIQAfPyCkWISRXEUCRC0ALboqaOZEx1IXdC9-UMj45PwM9na+YWxpCW5O4YHMGZvpbbOjj8O9d4-AEWmg2vg3hQsNB4GAthRzuloNYwvMoksHvEEjsMgl9p1IdDYfEEUibrk7uhlo9tC8DG9oB9Ol8cKNvEJ6GAQsoONxeKFktj0hQRH50PRRuhfPh1ltBT0+pIzpFdhMprNdLsCTC4dASdZrDhjNAAGK0WguITpd7YaAAbQA0tBRlQaAxmKweRA1ABdCi24wUe14lSICjc1S8B3e71I20KN3h3nEb04AD0ACpzHETWaLVaGdB8HaA9AAEQCtLpUvBz3C0Xi+CSmMAH0LeGLKzLMu2ler0AOteOCoGw2VFzVLbbHbkZcFfYHgi1RPhY-SAG4kTH06mcLv6CLxDzoPQzQAGKQGS9gS1HU3mm-qCiBFCg0JsRhSa9W22nmMmf+JBWuxZKEeBCNsIhCPA0LoAA7lUPwuJ+N4-t6TyWO4IAQJg77QMh36-gyAFrJsPbAWSYEQVBMHwdUUA1PhECoaqKEAIxoVYmHYU6H5fkxhH-mYWKViBOSUUgkHQY2tF-IxzGTGxHF4Bh6BYWCzw6EItDwQAokIWnSAkCAAG5gCAbC+FmM4JNAADUCkEUp+q7nuB4hseZoXpe-pxDWgi+jm95Wo+zRBK+OS4RiRFCUBOIUeBEnUdJCH2EhxScap3GRUagmJN2gqidoCWSTRKX0RifmIOhXE4R+OXEQV8VUVJcFlRADgVf2HqCNVmXqboWm6fpMRGfApnmZZJY2fZ6XKWULnlPMHm0KxFBeQYfEUHeeYQJoJjTKFL4hGYnULlVDIHRFdXZrlSQpCJTWJS1MmpRivVqTxeH1UJ+UPaBxVJa1dEQAxxiVbtGUfdlN0NX9YkA89bUdWDXUhhDyk1aBqSDdAekGVIo3jRZVmYnZJPofNQA)